# Make all lowercase letters capital in font file

Tags: html, css, fonts, truetype

I have a .ttf font file I created. I got all the capital characters, but not the lowercase. Is there a tool or easy way I could make all the lowercase letters the same as capital?

Example: The font should display "hello" as  "HELLO"

If that is not possible is there a way I can do this with HTML/CSS?

Comment: Why not create the lower-case letters, or acquire/purchase them or simply switch fonts? Otherwise YOUR PAGE WILL LOOK A LITTLE BIT SHOUTY. This is, usually, not a good thing.

Comment: it won't my page has a different font that will look good uppercase

Comment: Why not simply copy the uppercase glyphs into the lowercase positions as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, you can add CSS rule:

```
body {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

@DominatorX According to your answer, you can try something like this:

```
var allDomElems = $('body *'),
    helper;

allDomElems.each(function () {
    helper = $(this).text();
    helper = helper.toUpperCase();
    if($(this).children().length === 0) {
        $(this).text(helper);
    }
});
```

This doesn't work in all cases, so you'll have to debug the script.

Comment: Can I at least get credit (such as an upvote) please?

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure how to convert cases in HTML, CSS, or font files. There is a method in JavaScript that can convert strings though.

```
("string").toUpperCase(/*Enter substring value, by default it converts the whole string*/);
```

A similar method is used for "lowercasing":
`("string").toLowerCase();`

You could input the HTML content into JavaScript to convert the cases, then `document.write` them back out onto the page.